# How to get ASP.net (1.1) to look for the assembly.dll file in your Application Folder

Tags: asp.net

I'm running ASP.Net (vers 1.1) with code-behind that generates a assembly.dll file which it looks for in the Root/Bin folder of the WebServer.   My question is .... how can I get ASP.Net to look for my assembly.dll file in the Root/ Application folder / Bin folder?
Where "Application folder" is the folder from which my application is started containing the start-up WebForm.aspx file. The reason for my request is so that all my application files, including the assembly.dll file is nicely contained in or under my "Application folder"
I hope this question makes sense and is clear and relevent
Thanks - Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Got to Project Properties, Web tab, and set the path to the appropriate bin folder for the build.